# flowjs react children type Object | Array<Object>

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I have a component that wrap otrers (like a View / div). Right now it acepts a child and works ok but I would like that the component accept a child element or an array of them but can't do that with flowjs because of erro

> `React.Element` [1] is incompatible with array type [2].

This is the prop right now:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.Element<any>
}

...

render() {
  const { children } = this.props;

  return (
  <View> {children} </View>
  );
}
```

and this is what I'm trying to archive:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.Element<any> | Array<React.Element<any>>
}

...

render() {
  const { children } = this.props;

  const childList: Array<React.Element<any>> = children.constructor === Array ? children : [children];

  return (
    <View> {children.map(c=>c)} </View>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to archive this functionality without an error?

Solution (thanks to  Aleksey L. ) use Array.isArray() in case some modifications are needed or just simplify:

```
  <View>
    {Array.isArray(children) && children.map(c => c)}
  </View>
```

or

```
  <View>
    {children}
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refine the `children`'s type you can use `Array.isArray`:

```
const childList = Array.isArray(children) ? children : [children];
```

Now flow is convinced that `childList` is an `Array` and has `map` method.
[Type Refinements docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/)

**If you're not changing the children you could just use them as is (without `map` and without transforming single child to array): `<View>{children}</View>`.

Comment: Array.isArray(children) was the solution. Also, I thought that an array would break the app because it does with a Text component. Thanks.